# How to load test an ASP.NET Development Server hosted web application?

Tags: asp.net, load, stress-testing

I tried [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home) but it runs on linux, and the ASP.NET Development Server doesn't accept external connections.

I tried [Web Application Stress Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e2c0585a-062a-439e-a67d-75a89aa36495&displaylang=en) but I don't know how to specify the port, since I don't use :80 and it doesn't accept this syntax.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change your Dev Server to run on port 80?

Comment: I never configured its port, It always choose the port automatically, I don't know how to configure it yet, but you may have pointed a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) Software will allow you to do load testing of any web application - it works with both local and remote servers.

Keep in mind that the way ASP .NET Development Server handles connections you will not get a valid test result. It is designed to only accept connections from a local source and a very limited number of them at that (i think 2 or slightly more)

The load test should be performed on identical or very similar hardware to what is on production.